# Typescript compiling even with an error, TS2304

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm doing some tests with Typescript and even when I force an error the code is compiled to javascript. I'm using vscode tasks to compile.

**app.ts**

```
function getAllBooks() {
    let books = [
        { title: "book1", author: "author1", available: true },
        { title: "book2", author: "author2", available: false },
        { title: "book3", author: "author3", available: true }
    ];

    return books;
}


function logFirstAvailable(books) {
    let numberOfBooks = books.length;

    for (let book of books) {
        let firstAvailable = "";

        if (book.available) {
            firstAvailable = book.title;
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log('Total books: ' + numberOfBooks);
    console.log('First Available: ' + firstAvailable); // error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firstAvailable'.
}

const ALL_BOOKS = getAllBooks();
logFirstAvailable(ALL_BOOKS);
```

**app.js**

```
function getAllBooks() {
    var books = [
        { title: "book1", author: "author1", available: true },
        { title: "book2", author: "author2", available: false },
        { title: "book3", author: "author3", available: true }
    ];
    return books;
}
function logFirstAvailable(books) {
    var numberOfBooks = books.length;
    for (var _i = 0, books_1 = books; _i < books_1.length; _i++) {
        var book = books_1[_i];
        var firstAvailable = "";
        if (book.available) {
            firstAvailable = book.title;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('Total books: ' + numberOfBooks);
    console.log('First Available: ' + firstAvailable);
}
var ALL_BOOKS = getAllBooks();
logFirstAvailable(ALL_BOOKS);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--target", "ES5",
        "--outdir", "js",
        "--sourceMap",
        "--watch",
        "app.ts"
    ],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

If this is a normal behavior, how to block typescript to compile if any errors occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `--noEmitOnError`? Reading the args listed under `tsc --help` sounds like just the ticket.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--target", "ES5",
        "--outdir", "js",
        "--sourceMap",
        "--noEmitOnError",
        "--watch",
        "app.ts"
    ],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```